# Can't display data from my state/props in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that displays a single Article object that is fetched from a Mongo database. It goes through my reducer and then I use mapStateToProps to put the state into this.props. I then want to display the data from that object but I cannot figure out how to do so. The page is called ArticleShow (It shows one article.)

ArticleShow.js

```
class ArticleShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getArticle(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    // I know this is wrong
    const articleData = this.props.article;
    return (
      <Container>
       
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ArticleShow.propTypes = {
  getArticle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  article: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  article: state.article.articles,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getArticle })(ArticleShow);
```

articleReducer.js

```
const intialState = {
  articles: [],
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = intialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: {
          [action.payload._id]: action.payload,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
    }
```

Below is the data when I console.log(this.props.article). It contains all the data I want to display but nothing that I do allows me to display the data.

this.props.article

```
5f0f80157f7feb0a2512130a:
  author: "Shempton McGruntie"
  body: "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
  printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
  been "
  date: "2020-07-15T22:15:49.787Z"
  name: "Article_2"
  __v: 0
  _id: "5f0f80157f7feb0a2512130a"
  __proto__: Object
```

-- Note: I can change the payload by changing the index from ._id to name, but I have the exact same problem and cannot access any of the data.

articleReducer.js

```
const intialState = {
  articles: [],
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = intialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: {
          [action.payload.name]: action.payload,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
    }
```

this.props.article

```
Article_2:
  author: "Shempton McGruntie"
  body: "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
  printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
  been "
  date: "2020-07-15T22:15:49.787Z"
  name: "Article_2"
  __v: 0
  _id: "5f0f80157f7feb0a2512130a"
  __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

remember, passing javascript inside jsx requires {}

change :

```
 return (
      <Container>
        <p>articleData<p>
      </Container>
    );
```

to

```
return (
      <Container>
        <p>{articleData}<p>
      </Container>
    );
```

Comment: I shouldn't have put that in there. I knew It wouldn't have worked. My issue is more that I can't access the data for example this.props.article.Article_2.name or this.props.article.Article_2.author, it come back as undefined

Comment: I think I know why you can't access to the data because you didn't pass it as props to your component

Answer (score 0):

there is a tiny mistake I think related to articles in the initial state of the article reducer the response is object but the initial state of articles is array here is what I mean:

```
const intialState = {
  articles: [],
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = intialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: {
          [action.payload.name]: action.payload,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
    }
```

so instead of array change it to object like this:

```
const intialState = {
  articles: {},
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = intialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: {
          [action.payload.name]: action.payload,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
    }
```

Comment: It still shows all the data as undefined for example when I console.log(this.props.article.Article_2.name), it comes back as undefined even though I can see the data in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used to debug if something is not accessible from my store `state`

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>  {
  console.log("My store state ===>", state); // log the `state` and see the exact path for articles
  return ({
    article: state.article.articles,
  });
}
```

#### Edit

Default case is missing in `reducer`. Hope you have missed posting full code.

```js
export default function (state = intialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case GET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: {
          [action.payload._id]: action.payload,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
    default: return state; // You should have default case
    }
}
```